# Why to use tiled map in cocos2d game development

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am starting cocos2d and going through some online tutorials. The first question is arising in my mind is that is it necessary to use tiled map if yes then Why?

Can I not add a background image in scene to feel like a arena?

I want to make a arena which will have a long path in a field and player will run only on the path (similar to car race), and after a certain distance this will repeat. How will I make such environment in game. Idea, concept or reference links will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it necessary to use tiled map?

It is never really necessary to use a tiled map. For anything. However, it *is* helpful for many scenarios. So, in your case, **no**, it is not necessary. There are many other ways you can implement a repeating background or whatever.

> Can I not add a background image in scene to feel like a arena?

Yes, of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

No, a tiled map not necessary for your arena + long path concept, but it could work okay for that concept, if you wanted to.  Yes, you can add a background image instead.

Tiled maps are uniquely useful for tile-based games, or games where you want to dynamically change individual tiles while the game runs.

As for your "How will I make such environment in game" question:  this question is too big and I believe it goes against StackOverflow's guidelines.  So, my answer to your last question is another question: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... looking into ur reference